# How to adjust "time slots" in Ethereum 2.0 (Sharding + PoS)?

Tags: proof-of-stake, block-interval, sharding

In Ethereum 2.0 (Sharding and PoS), blocks are produced at a regular schedule, say once every `t` seconds.

What does this time slot depend on? The number of validators in the network who deposited Ether?
Is this time slot adjusted similar to the difficulty level of PoW (that is dependent on the total hashing power of the network)? Or it is a **fixed** value forever? If it is adjusted and is not fixed, is time slots duration dependent on the total deposited Ether in the network?

**P.S.** Regarding to the answer of `Lauri Peltonen`: Do you also understood how / why **12 seconds** has been chosen / calculated? For example, why not 10 seconds? or any other values? Meanwhile, I know that in Ethereum 2.0 there is no PoW and thus hashing power of the network does not matter, but also I said maybe as PoW difficulty is calculated based on hashing power of the network, here, time slot duration should be logically calculated based on **some parameters** in the network. **What are those parameters?**

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the time slots are static: 12 seconds per slot and 32 slots per epoch: 6,4 minutes per epoch.

So it should not change. It doesn't matter if there are transactions or not, empty slots are acceptable. A slot is a simply an option for a block to be included in the Beacon chain / shards.

The total hashing power of the network becomes irrelevant in PoS. Validators are assigned randomly to groups and not all validators need their hashing power at the same time. I also don't think the total number of validators matters too much although I'm unsure what happens if there are "too many" validators; maybe they are simply chosen at random from all available validators.

Most of this information comes from here although I never managed to read it till the end: https://ethos.dev/beacon-chain/

Comment: Thanks, but do you also understood how 12 seconds has been chosen / calculated? For example, why not 10 seconds ? or any other values ? Meanwhile, I know there is no PoW and thus hashing power does not matter, but also I said maybe as PoW difficulty is calculated based on hashing power of the network, here, time slot duration is also calculated based on some parameters in the network.

Comment: Sorry, no idea why it's exactly 12 seconds